# What is the meaning of setting text-rendering: optimizeLegibility in a css file?

Tags: css

What is the meaning of setting text-rendering to optimizeLegibility in a css file?? like this

```css
html {
   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-rendering/):

The text-rendering property in CSS allows you to choose quality of text over speed (or vice versa) allowing you to fine tune optimization by suggesting to the browser as to how it should render text on the screen.

MDN States: The text-rendering CSS property provides information to the rendering engine about what to optimize for when rendering text. The browser makes trade-offs among speed, legibility, and geometric precision.

optimizeLegibility is when the browser emphasizes legibility over rendering speed and geometric precision. This enables the use of special kerning and optional ligature information that may be contained in the font file for certain fonts.

Comment: Just a note about tradeoffs: If there is a lot of text on a page, using optimizeLegibility can have a significant performance penalty, especially on some mobile devices. So consider that before blindly adding this to the root element.